# Diagnose high swap usage on AIX

Tags: aix, swap

Which would be the best approach to diagnose high SWAP usage on an IBM AIX 6.3 machine?
I've already tried with `lsps -a` and `lslv`.

But also I'm looking for a strong scenario, like using `topas`.

Any approach is welcomed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at [svmon](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.prftools/idprftools_svmon.htm), [nmon](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds4/nmon.htm) and [ipcs](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/ipcs.htm). Here are some good articles on monitoring memory and paging space usage on AIX:

- [Optimizing AIX 7 memory performance: Part 2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix7memoryoptimize2/index.html) - Monitoring memory usage (developerWorks);
- [nmon analyser](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-nmon_analyser) - A free tool to produce AIX performance reports (developerWorks);
- [Analyze memory usage on AIX](http://www.unix.com/aix/217091-howto-analyze-memory-usage-aix-aka-svmon-101-a.html) (UNIX.COM);
- [Practical Guide to AIX: Memory](http://aix4admins.blogspot.com/2011/09/memory-leak-caused-by-program-that.html) (AIX for System Administrators);

[Using svmon to list the top 10 processes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.performance/mem_use_processes.htm) using memory on the system would look something like this:

```
# svmon -Pt10 | perl -e 'while(<>){print if($.==2||$&&&!$s++);$.=0 if(/^-+$/)}'
```

Comment: Thanks! Currently using nmon statistics to collect memory usage and evaluate corrective actions; but will check on your other links. Thanks again!!)

Answer (score -1):

```
ps avwx | head -1; ps avwx | sort +4n -r | head -10
```

Comment: Hi! You could make your answer much more helpful by explaining how it works, and how it relates to the question.